# Can component invoke a self destroy event

Tags: angular, angular2-components

I have a parent component which opens a new component on click of a link, this new component is supposed to have a close button which on close sends a closing message to parent and destroy itself.

We can send the closing message using `ngOnDestroy` method, but how do I invoke the destroying of the child component.

```ts
<parent>
    <child></child> //child to be opened on click but close 
                    //event should be inside the child componenet
</parent>
```

Do correct me if i am having some conceptual mistake here. Thanks

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you add a component using `ViewContainerRef.createComponent()` like shown in [Angular 2 dynamic tabs with user-click chosen components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468), then the component can destroy itself when you pass `cmpRef` to the created component.

Otherwise I don't think there is a way. You can pass a value to the parent so that an `*ngIf` removes the component.

```ts
<child *ngIf="showChild" (close)="showChild = false"></child>
```

```ts
class ParentComponent {
  showChild:boolean = true;
}
```

```ts
class ChildComponent {
  @Output() close = new EventEmitter();

  onClose() {
    this.close.emit(null);
  }
}
```

Comment: That's a neat solution, I also needed something like this few days ago and I did it exactly the same. Don't think there's a better way to achieve this at the moment.

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer can you show how to use "close" in the child component's typescript please? How will we trigger the close event?

Comment: anyway to do it for angular 1?

Comment: This is not the answer to this question. This is a component letting know the parent when to remove it. It's in the parent scope when the removal takes place... this is not self-destruction which is what the user was asking (what I came here for).

Comment: Also, it's misleading. It says the component is passing a component reference to the parent which is not true. It's just emitting an event that the parent has to subscribe to.

Comment: @JandroRojas sorry, don't understand what you are referring to.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer he is referring to the fact that the proposed mechanism is not entirely self-containted/encapsulated in a single component that destroys itself (based on some condition presummably).

Answer (score 21):

Here is another way to do it. This works from within the component itself; no need to communicate with external components.

```
// imports
export class SelfDestroyableComponent implements OnInit {
    // other code

    constructor(private host: ElementRef<HTMLElement>) {}

    // whatEver function name you want to give 
    onCloseClicked() {
        this.host.nativeElement.remove();
    }

    // other code
}
```

Comment: It works for me, but I don't know if this is the best practice

Comment: @ThPadelis I'm not sure whether this is the best practice either, but I am not aware of any drawbacks. Do you know where this will create issues?

Comment: Not sure, have to test some things I got on my mind. I'll let you know if I found any issue

Comment: Any drawbacks for this solution ? I would like to use it (didn't find something better) :)

Comment: @JoeAllen I've been using it. I haven't faced any yet.

Comment: @ArkaGhosh I'm currently using it too because I didn't find something better. No problem at the moment

Comment: It doesn't call "ngOnDestroy" if needed. And, if a listener is started with "HostListener" for example, it's not removed too. No automatic 'unsubscription'.

Comment: I've created a dialog component into which I can insert content externally. When I open and close and re-open the dialog I get all kinds of issues with icons not showing, invisible buttons remaining, form input elements not properly displaying. I've noticed this is due to the components I pass as content not being properly destroyed when the dialog is closed. Unfortunately, this isn't it, because it only removes the element from the DOM but doesn't end the component's life-cycle.

Comment: Why not calling the `ngOnDestroy` before the deletion ?

Answer (score 17):

Not sure about the cleanliness of such a solution, but I used:

```
this.viewContainerRef
    .element
    .nativeElement
    .parentElement
    .removeChild(this.viewContainerRef.element.nativeElement);
```

Comment: this is kinda hillarious, but does work and seems like a more proper answer than the accepted one.

Comment: What to assign to viewContainerRef?

Comment: This does exactly what I needed. I needed a "Self Destruct" click on a component that had been instantiated in an *ngComponentOutlet and this did the trick!

Comment: If you import `ElementRef` you can do the following during `AfterViewInit` lifecycle: `this.element.nativeElement.parentNode.removeChild(this.element.nativeElement);`

Comment: It'll make it disappear but the ngOnDestroy hook isn't called so isn't correct

Answer (score 0):

Another way to destroy (assuming a component created with `ViewContainerRef.createComponent()`) is to create a subject in the child component and subscribe to it from parent component, ie:

```
class ChildComponent {
  closeSubject = new Subject<boolean>();

  get closeObservable() {
    return this.closeSubject().asObservable();
  }

  deleteItself() {
    this.closeSubject.next(true);
  }
}
---
class ParentComponent() {
  // assuming you have something like: <ng-container #vcr></ng-container>
  @ViewChild('vcr', { static: true, read: ViewContainerRef })
  vcr: ViewContainerRef | undefined;
  
  createChildComponente() {
   ...
    const componentRef = this.vcr.createComponent(ChildComponent);
   // subscribe and destroy it
    componentRef.instance.closeObservable.subscribe((remove) => {
      if (remove) componentRef.destroy();
    })
  }

}
```